# What can be used to provide -5V potential to a circuit?

Tags: diodes, icl7107

What can be used to provide -(minus) 5 volts in the circuit diagram  given in the link below? 
Also can someone highlight what is the purpose of zener diodes?

[Simple digital meter using ICL7107](http://www.eleccircuit.com/let-s-build-a-simple-digital-meter-circuit-using-icl7107/)

Comment: `Also can someone highlight what is the purpose of zener diodes?` are you referring to zeners in general?

Answer (score 1):

> What can be used to provide -(minus) 5 volts in the circuit diagram given in the link below?

I have used the bootstrap circuit shown in the schematic below  and works pretty well (top section).

[image]

It uses 74HC04, the first two gates are used to generate an oscillation and then four gates are connected in parallel as an output stage to provide more output current to the bootstrap circuit (diodes/capacitors section).

---

There is also the circuit shown in the datasheet of [ICL7107](https://www.intersil.com/data/fn/fn3082.pdf)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Uh.... the answer to your question *is documented in the link you provide!*

[image]

This is the exact same circuit from @alexan_e's answer, only with an added obnoxious watermark.

There is even a functional description:

> The power supply Usually voltage as power of circuit, consisting of
>   positive, negative and ground. So to use, if you use laboratory
>   routine you may create a circuit that is not difficult.  But if you
>   want the ease of use. It may be switched to the battery. Combined the
>   circuit power on only one side, Then build up the negative voltage
>   converter circuit in Figure 4.
>
> The the circuit generates a negative voltage to the introduction of
>   the clock signal from pin 38 of IC1 Through the inverter by IC2-CD4049
>   is the negative voltage to supply the IC1 at pin 26.

It's not brilliantly written, but it's there.